LeetCode Rust solution for the Flip Columns problem #1072
Here is the solution to LeetCode Problem #1072.
The problem is to find the maximum number of rows in a matrix where all the values can be made equal after some columns are flipped. It's assumed that the matrix has only 0 and 1 values.
I would appreciate any ideas to make this code better. But, it's crucial not to break the performance.
use std::collections::HashMap;

impl Solution {

    fn get_compressed_view(row: &[i32]) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut result = Vec::new();
        let n = row.len();
        
        // Iterate over the row in chunks of 8 elements
        for i in (1..n).step_by(8) {
            let mut byte = 0u8;
            
            // Process each chunk and pack the result into a byte
            for value in &row[i..std::cmp::min(i + 8, n)] {
                byte <<= 1;
                if *value != row[0] {
                    byte |= 1;
                }
            }
            
            result.push(byte);
        }
        
        result
    }

    pub fn max_equal_rows_after_flips(matrix: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> i32 {
        let mut row_map = HashMap::new();
        
        for row in matrix {
            let compressed_view = Solution::get_compressed_view(&row);
            *row_map.entry(compressed_view).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
        
        // Find the maximum count of any compressed row signature
        *row_map.values().max().unwrap_or(&0)
    }
}


Very nice! I don't have enough comments for an answer. I'm not sure whether compiler is able to optimize that away, but if value != row[0] { byte |= 1 } can be simplified to unconditional byte |= (*value as u8) ^ (row[0] as u8) - a XOR is much cheaper than a conditional statement. But the problem requirement is the worst part of this: why use i32 where a bool would be sufficient?

Nice neat with XOR. We also elliminate if in this case that is usually good for branch predictor.

input Matrix type is external for me, so I can't change this part of code
